# TF26180: An item with this ID already exists in the input Array

Tags: tfs

I am using below flat query to get bug details for array of work item ids passed as argument.
 Below query works perfectly fine, but it throws error in some cases   "TF26180: An item with this ID already exists in the input Array"
 Reason is, ids array has duplicate ids, which is expected in my case. Is there any way to ignore this check or by pass this ?

```
                 var flatQuery = new Query(_store, detailsWiql.ToString(), ids);
                 WorkItemCollection workitems = flatQuery.RunQuery();

                foreach (WorkItem wi in workitems)
                 {

                    WorkItemType worktype = wi.Type;
                     worktypename = worktype.Name;
   }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can ignore or by pass this check, the exception is defined in `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common` assembly.  See https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSPlus.Tfs/0.0.1.104/Content/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common.xml

There is a doubt here, why you have duplicated work items?
Generally,  the work item ID is unique in TFS server.
I suggest you delete the duplicated work items first, backup them if needed, then create new work items to track the related tasks/features.

---

**UPDATE:**

As a workaround, you can try using the WIQL query with REST API to get the IDs first, See [A flat query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#a-flat-query). The write code to serach work item details with ID in loop. See [Get a workitem with REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#fully-expanded).

Besides, you can have a try with the [Wiql Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor), it can query the basic work item information directly.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the inputs, Is there any alternative method that meets my requirement ?

Comment: @Anil Kumar You can try to get the work item IDs first, then try REST API to get the details. See [Work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#by-ids)

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for your inputs. I tried the API it perfectly works, only issue is it gets workitems asynch, I would like to get it workitems synchronously, which can be done using                  var flatQuery = new Query(_store, detailsWiql.ToString(), ids);
                 WorkItemCollection workitems = flatQuery.RunQuery();
is there any way to get the workitems synchronously using Rest API

Comment: @AnilKumar If you want to get the workitem details, you have to get the work item IDs first. You can try using the WIQL query with REST API to get the IDs first, See [A flat query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#a-flat-query). Seems we can not get the workitems synchronously, need to write code to serach work item details with ID in loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, so when I was creating the `ids` array, I just ensured it was distinct:

```cs
// Capture ids of results in an array
var ids = (from WorkItemLinkInfo info in result select info.TargetId).Distinct().ToArray();

// Query a list of WorkItem IDs we want more info about
wiql = @"SELECT * FROM WorkItems";
q = new Query(App.workItemStore, wiql, ids);
var workItems = q.RunQuery();
```